# Как удалить gnome?

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS оконный менеджер LXDE. машина старая. Хотелось бы избавится от gnome, без серьезных последствий... слета дров и тд.

Answer (score 1):

По опыту знаю, что лучше снести все и переустановить линуху. А так можно:

```
aptitude purge gnome
```

Comment: хард кор :) так и сделал. thx XD

Comment: @gerroin, советую ещё после вписать `apt-get autoremove` - удалит ненужные пакеты

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get remove gnome